# Automorphism groups of domains of the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, linear-transformations, mobius-transformation

What is the automorphism group for $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$? Show that it has two connected components, and that the connected component containing the identity is transitive.

What is the automorphism group for $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0,1\}$? For each element of the automorphism group, find its order and the points in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0,1\}$ which are fixed under it.

By autmorphisms, I mean the 'set' (or in this group) of all biholomorphic functions from the space $X$ to itself ($X$ may be $\mathbb{C}^*$ or $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0,1\}$). With this terminology, I would say that $Aut(\mathbb{D})$ is the set of all linear fractional transformations $\frac{az-b}{cz-d}$ with $ad-bc\neq 0$.

We know that $Aut(\mathbb{C})$ is the set of all (non-constant) linear transformations/ I think that $Aut(\mathbb{C}^*)$ should be the set of all those linear transformations which take 0 to 0 and hence must be of the form $az$ for $a\neq 0$.

Comment: The series of commands you shout out in your question don't give any context (automorphisms of what structure on $\Bbb{C}$?). They also give no evidence of any work on your part. Hence my close vote.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by automorphisms of what structure on $\mathbb{C}$? When we say $Aut(\mathbb{C})$? don't we just mean biholomorphic functions from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Well my first guess for what $Aut(\Bbb{C})$ might mean was automorphisms of $\Bbb{C}$ as a field, so I think you do need to provide the context in your question (and some evidence of work on your part).

Comment: If you meant field automorphism this would have been a difficult question. There are many of those, but I can write only two.